# Never-completed type error when creating structure of function pointers in C

Tags: c, function, pointers, struct

I'm trying to create a structure which contains multiple function pointers, however when I try to create an instance of the structure I get a error `"variable "stCmdTable" was declared with a never-completed type"`.

I have a header file in which I have the following code:

```
typedef int (*pStCmd) (void);

struct stCmdStruc {
  pStCmd id;
  pStCmd measure;
  pStCmd setRelay;
};

typedef struct stCmdStruct stCmdStruct;

stCmdStruct stCmdTable;
```

I want to create `stCmdTable` and assign functions to all the function pointers in the stCmdTable, but when it doesn't like my declaration of `stCmdTable`.

I've also tried doing something like this, where I try to initialise all the function pointers to functions straight of the bat with my structure defintion, but it really doesn't like this telling me `expected a ";"` at the end of each line in the struct.

```
typedef int (*pStCmd) (void);

struct stCmdStruc {
  pStCmd id = sendId2;
  pStCmd measure = sendMeasurement2;
  pStCmd setRelay = setRelay2;
};

typedef struct stCmdStruct stCmdStruct;

stCmdStruct stCmdTable;
```

Can anyone please shed some light on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `struct stCmdStruc` != `struct stCmdStruct`. You typo'd

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). And then also include a copy-paste (as text) of the *full* and *complete* error output from the example, including any possible informational notes.

Comment: Please ask only one question in the question. Your second question is separate issue and should be asked separately.

Comment: C++ automatically introduces the structure name as a type name; C does not. Either use `struct` before `stCmdStruct` or add `typedef struct stCmdStruct stCmdStruct;`.

Comment: “C++ ...” yah, that modicum of convenience is like the free hit of heroin; what could go wrong if you try just a bit more....

Answer (score 1):

Try this . . .

```
typedef int (*pStCmd_Type) (void);

typedef struct _stCmdStruct {
  pStCmd_Type id;
  pStCmd_Type measure;
  pStCmd_Type setRelay;
} stCmdStruct_Type;

stCmdStruct_Type stCmdTable[your_table_size];

stCmdTable[0].id = sendId2;
stCmdTable[0].measure = sendMeasurement2;
stCmdTable[0].setRelay = setRelay2;
```